# How to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} x/a^x=0$?

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I want to prove that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x}{a^x} = 0,~~~~a>1.$$

Here's one approach: $a=1+p, p > 0$ and $k = [x]$, that is, $k$ is the largest integer that is equal or less than $x$. We note that $x-1 < k \leq x$.

As such, we get $a^x = (1+p)^x \geq (1+p)^k$, which we can expand using the binomial theorem. With some additional tricks, we can then prove what we wanted to prove.

My question: are there other (not incredibly complicated, and not l'Hopital based) proofs of the limit?

Comment: Hint: for $x>0$, bound $a^{x/2}$ below by [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), then prove $\frac{x}{a^x}<\frac2pa^{-x/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x}{a^x} = 0,~~~~a>1.
$$
We need to use here the **Taylor series**:
$$
a^{x}=\left(1+x\ln(a)+\frac{x^{2}\ln^{2}(a)}{2}+\frac{x^{3}\ln^{3}(a)}{6}+....\right)\tag{1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{{x}\to\infty}\dfrac{x}{a^x}=\lim_{{x}\to\infty}\dfrac{x}{\left(1+x\ln(a)+\frac{x^{2}\ln^{2}(a)}{2}+\frac{x^{3}\ln^{3}(a)}{6}+....\right)}=
\\
=\lim_{{x}\to\infty}\dfrac{x}{x\left(\frac{1}{x}+\ln(a)+\frac{x\ln^{2}(a)}{2}+\frac{x^{2}\ln^{3}(a)}{6}+....\right)}=
\\
=\lim_{{x}\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{x}+\ln(a)+\frac{x\ln^{2}(a)}{2}+\frac{x^{2}\ln^{3}(a)}{6}+....\right)}=
\\
=\lim_{{x}\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\left(0+\ln(a)+\frac{x\ln^{2}(a)}{2}+\frac{x^{2}\ln^{3}(a)}{6}+....\right)}=\lim_{{x}\to\infty}{0}=0.
$$